# How to do router auth guard? Getting Observable<User> From AngularFireAuth then converting to boolean for the guard

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm using the router guard with AngularFireAuth to check if the user may enter the route. The problem is, AngularFireAuth returns a `<User>` type, while the guard needs a `<boolean>` type.

I got an error message in my sublime text: **'Type User is not assignable to type boolean'**

---

I'm following this tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/

I have no idea, how to convert the  that was retrieved from AngularFireAuth type to  for the router guard.

This is the **auth.service**

```
interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  favoriteColor?: string;
}


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) {

      //// Get auth data, then get firestore user document || null
      this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
          if (user) {
            return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
          } else {
            return of(null)
          }
        })
      )
    }
```

This is the **auth.guard**

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

      return this.auth.user.pipe()
           take(1),
           map(user => !!user),
           tap(loggedIn => {
             if (!loggedIn) {
               console.log('access denied')
               this.router.navigate(['/login']);
             }
         })
    )
```

The error **'Type User is not assignable to type boolean'** comes from `return this.auth.user.pipe()`. in **auth.guard**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. I just saw the comment section on that blog.

There was a typo in the code there:

```
return this.auth.user.pipe()
           take(1),
```

should be

```
return this.auth.user.pipe(
           take(1),
```

Now it works.